# How to control a servo

Tags: integrated-circuit, pwm, servo

As servos use PWM and duration pulse determines the angle, the way to control a servo is via programming or an IC component is required?

Comment: That's one way, though original applications used analog pulse generator circuits controlled by the variable resistors in the RC transmitter sticks (those of course are almost all now digital)

Comment: Usually, the servo command pulses are made by controlling an I/O pin directly from the μC software.  On a different note, however, there are some interesting exceptions.  For example, [OpenServo](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9014), which gets commands through I2C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need a separate IC if 1) all the PWM outputs on your MCU are in use (or it doesn't *have* any in the first place and you can't create any), and 2) your MCU is too busy to perform software PWM. Otherwise, programming the MCU to use or emit PWM in software will do.

Comment: As angle positioning depends on the length of the pulse, can I send signals via an analog stick for all possible angles, or just "right" and "left"?

Comment: @dempap: http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6992-1

Comment: @dempap as long as you can read the analog stick's (typically) two potentimeters, you could then program your microcontroller to send the right servo command. The "angle" is determined in your code. All you can send to the servo is left or right, and how fast/slow.

Comment: Just to clarify ... look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_control this shows that any angle can be sent. Not just "right" and "left" but between 0 to 90 degrees left or right (and usually a bit more). It's all about how much pulse width you send.

Answer (score 3):

You can also control a servo position with a simple 555 timer circuit and a potentiometer. For instance:

http://www.hvlabs.com/555servo.html